# Microsoft JET Database Engine error: "file in use"

Tags: ms-access, iis, asp-classic, database-connection, vps

I encountered this strange behavior in working with database in Classic ASP.

I had a database in a public location: /database/database.mdb (www browsable location).
This is translated to the following physical: c:\Domains\mysite.com\database\database.mdb

I decided to change the database location and put it in the following non public location, for added security: c:\Domains\Contents\database.mdb

All ASP scripts can access this location and it has the adequate permissions.

There are some scripts that work with multiple recordsets that open and close simultaneously, for example, in the following flow:

```
|-database is opened
| |---recorset1 is opened
| | 
| | |----recorset2 is opened
| | | 
| | |----recorset2 is closed
| | 
| | |-recorset3 is opened
| | |
| |---recorset1 is closed
|   |
|   |-recorset3 is closed
|
|-database is closed
```

The problem is this: When I use the database in the public location (c:\Domains\mysite.com\database\database.mdb) - The described work with recordsets above works great. But when I use the database in this non public location (c:\Domains\Contents\database.mdb) I get the following 
error:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'
>   Could not use ''; file already in use.

I have 2 questions:

1. How is this possible? Does IIS treat public http files different from 'local' files? How can I fix this?
2. Does this really have an added security? Is it really effective?

Comment: `I had a database in a public location: /database/database.mdb (www browsable location).` this is disaster. security issue.

Comment: `But when I use the database in this non public location (c:\Domains\Contents\database.mdb) I get the following error:` does your IUSR user has READ/WRITE access to this database?

Comment: Why in 2016 are people STILL attempting to use Access databases for Web Development? Save yourself a lot of grief and switch to [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/cloud-platform/sql-server-editions-express), it's free, efficient, designed to be scale-able.

Comment: @Zam - IUSR user has READ/WRITE permissions. The code works great when only one recordSet is open at any given time.

Comment: @Lankymart - I still use Access database since it's much easier to build and develop the database locally, as a file-based database, and then only upload one single file, instead of having to deal with complicated deployment of SQL Server Express that uses a client/server model. All this, while keeping in mind that there are no significant differences between MS Access and SQL Server Express for databases up to 2GB. My plan is to move to SQL Server after finishing the development. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Complicated? I run SQL Server Express locally, once i'm ready for a true server environment, detech, copy mdf and ldf files to server, attach and away I go. You may it's less complicated but Access was never designed to work in a multi-user environment *(case in point workgroup files...yuk!)* so your actually giving yourself more grief then working in a true multi-user relational database.

Comment: `The code works great when only one recordSet is open at any given time.` sound like not allowed concurent connection.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by no significant differences. There are loads of differences in syntax you need to be aware of if you're querying JET rather than SQL Server. http://accessdatabasetutorial.com/2013/12/30/sql-commands-ms-access-sql-versus-sql-server/

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but do you have your database open in the Access desktop application while you're trying to view data from it in your website?

Comment: @John - No. The database is not opened in Access Desktop. It can read and write from\to database, but only one recordSet at any given time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for getting the following error, when trying to open multiple recordSets simultaneously:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'
>
> Could not use ''; file already in use.

was insufficient permissions to the directory of the database.

In plesk, I added these permissions to the directory containing the database (c:\Domains\Contents)
[image: Directory Permissions in Plesk]

And this solved the problem.

This is related to the ability of IIS to create new files (database.ldb) in the directory containing the database. An .LDB file is a Microsoft Access Lock information file, and is created when an Access database is opened/accessed by a user, and contains information about which users are currently accessing the file. The .ldb file plays an important role in the multiuser scheme of the Microsoft Jet database engine versions 3.0 and 3.5, as it is used to **determine which records are locked in a shared database and by whom.**

More on this here: [Introduction to .ldb Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/136128)

> ...the .mdb file should be located in a folder where users have read,
>   write, create, and delete (or full control) permissions.

Comment: So, what was suggested to you in the first place, not surprising really.

Answer (score 1):

> "You may have permission to open the database,but does the account trying to access the database have permission? Most likely it's not the logged in user but rather the anonymous user"

how do we check that the account trying to access the database have permission?

Refer https://forums.iis.net/t/1147247.aspx?Microsoft+JET+Database+Engine+error+80004005+

for more details

Comment: Thank you. That indeed was a permissions problem.